# Send a list using django message framework

Tags: django, python-3.x

In short, I am struggling to extract list contents that were passed to the template using the message framework.

In long: My webapp has an import transactions capability where the user selects a csv and I upload each record to the database. For records that fail, I am storing these as a list, such that I can display on the next page which transactions weren't successful. Each transaction has a number of fields, so essentially its a list of lists.

Simply, I create an 'errorRecords' list, which I then loop over and add to the message framework.

The data gets to the template just fine, but I am struggling to use normal list operations to extract the data correctly.

Have looked at similar code passing dicts and json, but the similar approach, just using a list doesn't seem to work for me.

Creation of the message in the View:

```
for item in errorRecords:
    messages.add_message(request, messages.WARNING, item)
```

The problem then comes at the template stage:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ message[0] }}</td>
        <td>{{ message[1] }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Which gives the following error:
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'message[0]'

I've also tried `message.message[0]` which gives a similar result ( django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Could not parse the remainder: '[0]' from 'message.message[0]').

I know the data is there, because if I use this...

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <tr>
         <td>{{ message.message }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

...the entire list shows in the first cell of the table row, so I'm perplexed as to why if `message.message` is a list, then why I cannot access its items using `message.message[0]`, etc

So really, all I'm trying to do is extract each list item (message in messages), then extract each item's field and insert into a table cell so I end up with a table of fields.

Comment: I believe this should have been just `{{ message }}`, not `{{ message.0 }}` or `{{ message.message }}`.

Answer (score 0):

In the template, list index is done with [dot notation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#variables), so  instead of

```
{{ message[0] }}
```

try doing this

```
{{ message.0 }}
```

Comment: Opps! Thanks!. But....now it doesn't error, but there are no values showing in my table....? It does however, show that it is creating the correct number of table rows relating to each failed record, but yeah, there's no values. There is data there, because if I do ```{{ message.message.0 }}``` then it renders with one character in each cell....(and they show!).

Comment: And I've tried changing ```{{ message.0 }}``` to ```{{ 'test' }}``` and the 'test' string shows in the table, just so you know its not a css/colour problem.

Comment: Try just {{message}}

Comment: {{ message }} shows in the table, just with the entire list printed in the single cell.

Comment: ok i think i know why.....

The list isn't actually a list. It is just a string that looks like a list. I'll post another question to this problem, but I think the string coming from message is "['field1','field2','field3']" so it is a string, not a list.